# React redux form wizard with remote submit

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Let's assume I have 2 steps in my wizard form. Step1 - get username, Step2 - get surname. Let's also assume that I want to have a vertically navigable form, so that after completing Step1 I want to scroll down to Step2, without closing Step1. Please note, that when in Step2 we have Step1 form and Step2 form in the body. Now I have a remote submit button to dispatch a submit request. It doesn't work for Step2 since I am dispatching the request that reaches Step1 again, not Step2..

My question is, how can I do that if I have 2  objects with the same name (it'a wizard, I collect the results at the end) on the same page?

If I show each step separately, meaning when Step2 is being displayed, Step1 is not in the DOM, it works with no problems. I know my problem is that I have these 2 guys being named the same, do you have any ideas how that could be worked around?

Cheers,
Adam

Comment: I just made a similar wizard. Make an object for each step. You also need to create unique ids for the html to link properly.

Comment: Hi SILENT, could you please provide some simple example of what you meant by that? Would I still use the redux-form wizard logic somehow or have my own handling of the steps via some objects?

Comment: or do you simply mean to have sth like form: form1 for step1, do remote submit for form1 id and store the results in parent, then form2 for step2, remote submit on form2, handle the results, combine and do some final submit?